# Boost lib directory changing after building

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have built Boost 1.5.8 on windows using VS 2013 after re-installing Windows OS. Earlier my x64 libs were in C:\Boost\lib\x64 but now they are in C:\Boost\lib. 
I have great many projects with libs path set to earlier one. I wanna know if I create the x64 folder inside lib and copy all the lib files will it still work?

Also, please tell me when I built Boost previously both i386 and x64 libs were built. With previously mentioned x64 to contain 64bit libs. Now I had to built those two libraries separately. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you show me the commands you used to build boost library....

Comment: Boost doesn't normally build multiple archs. So you probably had more steps earlier, and you forgot to document them for yourself :) I usually build different archs and copy `stage/lib` to where I want them. Is there anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Hi, @sehe yes do not remember clearly the steps I did in previous installation. This is the command I used for building

`b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete --abbreviate-paths architecture=x86 address-model=32 install -j4`
<br>
for 64 bit, 
`b2 toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete --abbreviate-paths architecture=x86 address-model=64 install -j4`

Answer (score 0):

I think your x64 directory was either manually created, or came from some binary installer. The standard build process never creates "x64" directory or "i386" directory. Also, it does not build both 32 and 64 bit versions; on Windows 32-bit libraries are normally built unless you specify `address-model=64` or take other steps.

So, you did not do anything wrong; you can move libraries around to match your project setup.